# How to use Django {% csrf_token %} in bootstrap popver

Tags: javascript, python, django, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using bootstrap popover to pop a small form.
how do I get the {% csrf_token %} to work inside the javascript popover.

```
$('.delete_btn').popover({ 
      html: 'true', placement: 'top', title: 'Are you sure?', 
      content: '<form action="{{object.get_delete_url}}" method="post">
               {% csrf_token %}<div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Confirm" />
               </div></form>' 
    });
```

Thank you all in advance

Edit:

Now I've solved the issue with csrf_token but unable to solve the issue with getting absolute url.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same problem myself a few days ago. You said that you found the answer, but I figured I might as well post it here for any others who might stumble across this problem.

When django puts the csrf token tag into html, it creates an invisible html  tag. The problem I ran across is, it does so with single quotes:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='sometokeninhere' />
```

This is a bit strange to me, because double quotes are standard, and I am currently investigating the reasoning behind these single quotes. Another problem I ran across is that django variables (i.e. `{{ form.variable1 }}`) that I was putting into the popover were being rendered as input tags with double quotes. Fail. So, the fix that I used is to grab the csrf token variable from the context and using it to make my own hidden input, replacing the `{% csrf_token %}` with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}" >
```

Comment: The way I solved the csrf is by passing {% csrf_tokem %} as a variable in the template like that <script>var csrf = {% csrf_token %}</script> and than I was able to read in the JS the variable 'csrf'.
But this only solve the issue with reading {% something %} and I am still stuck with {{ something }}, its not working in the template script